# List of forward links on mediawiki page

Tags: mediawiki

I am using a Mediawiki site as a personal [Zettelkasten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zettelkasten). The zettelkasten is basically a collection of notes that should be linked to one another, making a wiki a good place to store one. The linking between the notes is the key feature of the zettelkasten. So for each "note" (i.e., page on my wiki), I need a list of 1) how to get to that page and 2) where you can go from that page. The first part is easy, since I can use the built-in `{{Special:Whatlinkshere/{{PAGENAME}}}}`. However, I can't figure out how to create a similar list of forward links from each page. Is there a way to do this within mediawiki, or an extension that can do this? What is the best way to gather a list of all (internal) links on a given wiki page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install [DynamicPageList3](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DynamicPageList3), you can use `{{#dpl: linksfrom = {{FULLPAGENAME}} }}`.

With [Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto), you can define `Module:Links` with `inner` function:

```lua
local p = {}
function p.inner (frame)
    local wikitext = frame:preprocess (mw.title.new (frame.args [1]):getContent ())
    local link_set = {}
    -- Find all occurences of [[...]]:
    for title in  mw.ustring.gmatch (wikitext, '%[%[([^%#|%]]+)%]%]') do
        -- Remove #... or |...:
        title = mw.text.trim (mw.ustring.gsub (title, '[#|][^%]]*', '', 1))
        if title ~= '' then
            link_set [title] = true
        end
    end
    local links = {}
    for link, _ in pairs (link_set) do
        links [#links + 1] = '[[' .. link .. ']]'
    end
    table.sort (links)
    return table.concat (links, ', ')
end

return p
```

and call it like this: `{{#invoke:Links|inner|{{FULLPAGENAME}}}}`. But this is expensive, and you mat need to filter `title`s better, if you have *Semantic MediaWiki* installed. There also will be issues with synchronisation (the list of links will be one version behind the page it is in, until a purge).